# PriorityQueue insert Method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an issue recreating the insert or add method of java's `PriorityQueue` class.

There are a couple stipulations:

- the main one is that I'm not allowed to use anything from `java.util.*` that includes `ArrayList`.
- I know that the queue must sort by some priority, in this case I sort money. The item that I am inserting into the queue looks like this

  ```
  Penny,1971,4
  Nickel,2002,9
  Five,1980,2
  etc....
  ```

So when I take the `substring(0, 3)` in the code below I'm really just taking the first 3 letters of the word because I want to have the `PriorityQueue` sort the items based on alphabetical order so `Dime, Nickel, Penny, Quarter etc.`

I use some code from the insertion sort algorithm to sort the items coming into the queue.

The issue is that it correctly inserts the first item into the queue but I get the

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25
```

On the line

```
array[x] = array[x - 1];
```

the length of the array element is 25...

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I could do better? I stumped on this problem....

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
@Override
public void insert(Money item) {
    int x;

    if(numElems == 0) {
        array[numElems++] = item;  //if its the first item simply insert it no need to worry about sorting
    } else {
        x = numElems;

        while(x > 0 && item.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(array[x - 1].toString().substring(0, 3)) > 0) {   

            array[x] = array[x - 1];
            x--;
        }

        array[x] = item;
        numElems++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the array is 25, then the max index you can retrieve is 24. Remember, arrays start at index 0.

Comment: yes i believe I added the element at position 24 because the priorityQueue inserts from the rear and removes from the from (position 0) thats why i thought decrementing x (x--;) would work because I add the element at position 24 then add the element at position 23 etc.... but its not working for me

Comment: What is the initial value of `numElems`, 24 or 0?

Comment: the initial value of numElems is set to 0 when its called by the constructor!

Comment: It looks alright... the only thing I can think of that is causing your `ArrayIndexOutofBounds` is that you're adding more than 25 items..